# Streaming music service with offline playlists?

Tags: webapp-rec, offline

I'm an iPod Touch user with a daily commute to work of about 45 minutes. While listening to podcasts and my library is great, my music gets to be very old. At work I frequently listen to Last.fm and Pandora; but it would be nice to find a service that had streaming and offline playlists.

Anything with offline playlists that'll work with my iPod Touch (4th Gen, 32 GB model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TuneIn supports streaming radio, the pro version can record streams as well - that should give you the offline playlist feature.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading something about [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com) being able to support iPods. You do need a premium subscription though, and in some regions it might not be available.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Rdio](http://www.Rdio.com) which I use to create playlists that I sync with my iPod touch and iPad for offline listening. It will cost you $10/month but well worth the price.